# How to download the Image which is pointed by Image button in android chat application

Tags: android, android-layout, google-cloud-messaging, android-imagebutton

How to download the image which is pointed by  Image button  in android .I have dynamically created this image button using the image url from the server.Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look at Picasso.It did wonders for me.
Heres the link [Picasso Android tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-working-with-picasso--cms-22149)

Comment: Is there any option for creating dynamic Image buttons in Picasso?